# Image drag'n'drop in a contenteditable element moving between text/inner elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

So I have a contenteditable=true div, of which there are images and text within this div. I would like to drag the images within this div to move the image around while shuffling and pushing the text away. How can I do this?

Thanks!

PS: I tried jquery-ui draggable/droppable, but I do not want it as a floating div. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the jquery [.sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) function on all the items you want to be moveable

$("img").sortable();

And having the images have a style of display:inline (otherwise everything would break to a new line), but for the text to wrap around the images instead of being on the side or to break to another line they would need the float  style.

Comment: Doesn't work for me with the latest version of chrome.